# Moving array via ajax from PHP to JS with valid JSON format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I started with an array from php, which when called via ajax looked like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {id:"12",from:"09:00:00",to:"15:00:00"}
    [1] => {id:"13",from:"08:00:00",to:"10:00:00"}
    [2] => {id:"12",from:"15:00:00",to:"17:00:00"}
)
```

PHP code

```
public static function getBookedTime($date) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE cid = ".$_SESSION["cid"]." AND doc_date='".strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($date))."'";
    $result = self::qry($query);


    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        $obj = "{";
        $obj.= 'id:'.'"'.$line["person_id"].'",';
        $obj.= 'from:'.'"'.$line["from_time"].'",';
        $obj.= 'to:'.'"'.$line["to_time"].'"';
        $obj.= "}";  

        $time_array[] = $obj; 

    }

    print_r( json_encode($time_array) );

}
```

So I added json_encode($myarray) to the PHP and also added  JSON.parse(response) to the javascript.  Now in my page, after being called via ajax, it looks like this:

```
var booking1 = {id:"12",from:"09:00:00",to:"15:00:00"},{id:"13",from:"08:00:00",to:"10:00:00"},{id:"12",from:"15:00:00",to:"17:00:00"};
```

The trouble is, I still cannot access any of the values. This is not a valid format in js.

Using either JS or php, how can I get booking1 to look like booking2 (or any valid format)?  I tried array.push and about a thousand things but it just won't budge.

```
var booking2 = [
    {id:"12",from:"09:00:00",to:"15:00:00"},
    {id:"13",from:"08:00:00",to:"10:00:00"},
    {id:"12",from:"15:00:00",to:"17:00:00"}
  ];
```

(jQuery answers are ok!)

Comment: You need to add the code that does the encoding, but it looks like you are encoding individual values instead of the final resulting array.

Comment: As above. You are json_encoding in a loop while creating the array. Append the array in the loop, then after the loop json_encode

Comment: I don't understand.  Should I add the php code or the ajax code to the question?

Comment: Php code. Please

Comment: Thanks - I write front-end code & this makes my head hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your edit: You should not attempt to build a json string manually in your loop. Instead, add the values you need to an array and add that.

Also note that you need to `echo` and not use `print_r()` as that will invalidate your json.

And if you only select the fields you need, it is even easier:

```
public static function getBookedTime($date) {
    $query = "SELECT person_id, from_time, to_time FROM booking WHERE cid = ".$_SESSION["cid"]." AND doc_date='".strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($date))."'";

    $result = self::qry($query);

    echo json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}
```

**Note:** You should also use a prepared statement with bound variables to avoid sql injection. That might not be possible here due to the values used, but using it everywhere is always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Don't create your own json string use json_encode instead, it will do all the hard work for you in a much more precise way.

```
public static function getBookedTime($date) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE cid = ".$_SESSION["cid"]." AND doc_date='".strftime("%Y-%m-%d",strtotime($date))."'";
    $result = self::qry($query);


    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $time_array[] = ["id" =>$line["person_id"], "from" => $line["from_time"], "to" =>$line["to_time"]];
    }
    $json = json_encode($time_array);
}
```

$json is now a correctly formatted json string that you can pass on to JavaScript.

Comment: Both answers are correct - this one just needs an 'echo' (took me a minute to get it).  This one has the advantage that you can name the vars however you want.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle sorry, didn't understand that you wanted to echo the json. But yes you create an associative array that gets json_encoded, that means the variables can be different and you can structure the array differently too. Such as `$time_array[$line["person_id"]] = ["id" =>$line["person_id"], "from" => $line["from_time"], "to" =>$line["to_time"]];` which means the id is the key in the array making it easy to find a particular subarray if it's the id that is the search term